# 2 Select From Statements, Group from 3rd Table

Tags: sql-server

Im very new to SQL 2012, and need your help please. I have managed to put together the following query and it works, just fails when I try to group by a category type from a 3rd table. Not sure how to join, but getting a bound error.

So basically, the 2 where(select from) statements work, but I cant get c.category. (table name: ELM_HO.dbo.BCX_ExclusionsJan2013)

Please can you provide guidance. Thank you

```
SELECT c.category
    ,count (c.category)
      ,count(distinct b.[ACCOUNT NUMBER])
    ,sum([30 DAYS BAL]) as [30 DAYS]
      ,sum([30 DAYS VAT BAL]) as [30 DAYS VAT]
      ,sum([60 DAYS BAL]) as [60 DAYS]
      ,sum([60 DAYS VAT BAL])as [60 DAYS VAT]
      ,sum([90 DAYS BAL]) as [90 DAYS]
      ,sum([90 DAYS VAT BAL]) as [90 DAYS VAT]
      ,sum([REST]) as [REST]
      ,sum([VAT REST]) as [REST VAT]
    ,sum(b.[30 DAYS BAL]) + sum(b.[30 DAYS VAT BAL])+ sum(b.[60 DAYS BAL]) + sum(b.[60 DAYS VAT BAL]) + sum(b.[90 DAYS BAL]) + sum(b.[90 DAYS VAT BAL]) +sum(b.[REST]) + sum(b.[VAT REST]) as [TOTAL PAYMENTS]
  FROM [ELM_BP348].[dbo].[BP348JUL2013] as b]
  where b.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] in (SELECT [Account Number] FROM [TIMS].[dbo].[TIMS90-Claim_JUL2013])
  and b.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] in (select [Account no] from ELM_HO.dbo.BCX_ExclusionsJan2013 as c)
  group by c.category
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any data I wasn't able to test this, but I think it might be what you want:

```
SELECT 
    c.category,
    COUNT(c.category),
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.[ACCOUNT NUMBER]),
    SUM([30 DAYS BAL]) as [30 DAYS],
    SUM([30 DAYS VAT BAL]) as [30 DAYS VAT],
    SUM([60 DAYS BAL]) as [60 DAYS],
    SUM([60 DAYS VAT BAL])as [60 DAYS VAT],
    SUM([90 DAYS BAL]) as [90 DAYS],
    SUM([90 DAYS VAT BAL]) as [90 DAYS VAT],
    SUM([REST]) as [REST],
    SUM([VAT REST]) as [REST VAT],
    SUM(b.[30 DAYS BAL]) + SUM(b.[30 DAYS VAT BAL])+ SUM(b.[60 DAYS BAL]) + SUM(b.[60 DAYS VAT BAL]) + SUM(b.[90 DAYS BAL]) + SUM(b.[90 DAYS VAT BAL]) +SUM(b.[REST]) + SUM(b.[VAT REST]) as [TOTAL PAYMENTS]
  FROM [ELM_BP348].[dbo].[BP348JUL2013] AS b
  INNER JOIN ELM_HO.dbo.BCX_ExclusionsJan2013 AS c ON b.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] = c.[Account no]  
  WHERE b.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] in (SELECT [Account Number] FROM [TIMS].[dbo].[TIMS90-Claim_JUL2013])
  GROUP BY c.category
```

You could probably replace the WHERE clause with another inner join too.

Comment: Hi JPW, thanks a million. "Genius" it actually returned something and I flipped. I would love to send you the data to test but they huge files and don't know if you have time, or how to get to you.  I was trying to replicate the results, but I am afraid  the summary does not match. in all fairness the guy who did it first, could have made an error. just needed to know for sure.

Comment: Results from Your Script:)

Comment: Results from Your Script: category (No column name) 30 DAYS 30 DAYS VAT 60 DAYS 60 DAYS VAT 90 DAYS 90 DAYS VAT REST REST VAT TOTAL PAYMENTS
COUNCILLORS 35 9225.39 986.74 1794.88 186.36 904.42 82.78 36836.95 3495.69 53513.21
GOVERNMENT 264 599314.73 36422.36 628511 43065.94 1215691.55 30251.78 14732380.51 577006.99 17862644.86
EMPLOYEES 518 279034.69 33908.89 122822.16 14799.26 59619.19 7410.53 452202.68 42479.15 1012276.55

Comment: Results from the 1st person:

Comment: Unique Acc's 30 Days 30 Days (VAT) 60 Days 60 Days (VAT) 90 Days 90 Days (VAT) Rest  Rest (VAT) Summary
...Government 264 R 488,428.83 R 21,578.22 R 506,324.63 R 25,993.55 R 1,126,253.48 R 17,736.13 R 13,242,783.59 R 368,465.73 R 15,797,564.16
...Council 23 R 5,399.15 R 560.89 R 1,782.46 R 186.36 R 904.42 R 82.78 R 24,896.57 R 1,996.10 R 35,808.73
...Employees 518 R 135,549.24 R 16,318.31 R 56,873.53 R 6,718.70 R 27,717.02 R 3,343.96 R 207,837.71 R 19,930.56 R 474,289.03